# SAS max in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sas

Trying to reengineer a SAS code in SQL Server.
Code has a proc-sql file with the following statement.

```
   sum(case when max(t1,t2) = 0 and transac='D'  THEN sales else 0 end)/sum(sales)
```

I tried to convert it to SQL using the below, but it is apparently incorrect.
Hoping someone here can point out the right approach.

```
 sum(case when (select max(Tval) from  values(t1,t2) as TVal) = 0 AND transac = 'D' THEN sales else 0)/nullif(sum(sales),0)
```

Also tried:

```
  sum(case when (t1 > t2 AND t1 = 0 OR t2 > t1 AND t2 = 0) AND transac ='D' THEN SALES ELSE 0 END)/nullif(sum(sales),0)
```

However, could not replicate the SAS result using this approach.

Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Thanks,
B

Comment: Are t1,t2 columns?

Comment: Thanks @Simon Yes, t1 and t2 are columns

Comment: Can you provide some data to show us where it differs?

Comment: Are you trying to count each time t1 = 0 `AND` t2 = 0 `AND` transac = D ?

Comment: which type of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming t1 and t2 are columns...

You can use a CTE

```
WITH CTE1
AS
(SELECT MAX(t1), MAX(t2)
FROM fooTable),

CTE2
AS
(SELECT 
CASE WHEN
SUM(t1 + t2) = 0 AND MAX(fooTable.transac) = 'D' THEN sales
ELSE 0
END AS fooColumn
FROM CTE1, fooTable)

SELECT SUM(fooColumn) / SUM(table.sales)
FROM CTE2, table
```

I think something like this might work... but I think the MAX(fooTable.transac) might also mess something up. Are you able to provide a small sample data of what you're working with?

Answer (score 0):

You might check if the SQL server has a function that is similar to the MAX(,) function in SAS or the LARGEST(,) function in Teradata.

If not then just simulate it with a CASE statement. Replace

```
max(t1,t2)
```

with

```
case when (t1>t2) then t1 else t2 end
```